# Need to deploy a file to the MSTest shadow directory that is used in TestInitialize()

Tags: unit-testing, deployment, mstest

I have a unit test that deploys a database using a .bak file in the TestInitialize method. I'm running this test from mstest using the dll (not from VS) so I need the .bak file to get copied to the shadow directory that mstest creates.

I don't want to add [DeploymentItem] attributes to every test method, I'm not even sure that would work since the TestInitialize is the method that is consuming this file.

Is there a tag I can put in the project that will guarentee that the .bak file will get copied to the shadow directory when running using MSTest on the test DLL?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See Deployment Items: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475(v=vs.80).aspx